# Cannot execute IEDriver or ChromeDriver through TeamCity BuildAgent on Windows 7

Tags: selenium, teamcity, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

My team is looking into using Selenium 2 for our UI testing. Our UI development is being done by an external vendor (a topic for another time) and using the RemoteDriver(server/client) would be require more maintenance than productivity on our end.

My test project is a simple maven project where I try to launch a new IE(v8 - 64bit)/Firefox/and Chrome browser and see if it will successfully navigate to some arbitrary url.  It runs locally on my machine and on remotely on TeamCity build-agent user profile (go to the source project and run mvn test).  However, when I try to execute the test through the TeamCity console (web or through remote run on IntelliJ) I get the following errors:

**IE Driver Error**

```
[17:19:57][it:test] Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
[17:19:57][it:test] 2.25.3.0
[17:19:57][it:test] Listening on port 34154
[17:20:00][it:test] Oct 23, 2012 5:20:00 PM   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
[17:20:00][it:test] INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
[17:20:00][it:test] Oct 23, 2012 5:20:00 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
[17:20:00][it:test] INFO: Retrying request
[17:20:01][it:test] [1A [32mWhen [0m [32mI launch " [0m [32m [1mie [0m [32m" on   TeamCity [0m [90m# Browser_Steps.I_launch_browser_on_TeamCity(String) [0m
[17:20:01][it:test] [90mThen [0m [90mI should see that the browser was launched [0m [90m# Browser_Steps.I_should_see_that_the_browser_was_launched() [0m
[17:20:02][it:test] [1A [31mThen [0m [31mI should see that the browser was launched [0m [90m# Browser_Steps.I_should_see_that_the_browser_was_launched() [0m
[17:20:02][it:test] [31morg.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present
[17:20:02][it:test] Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
[17:20:02][it:test] System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_33'
[17:20:02][it:test] Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
[17:20:02][it:test] Session ID: 2244723f-8097-4a0d-9e9b-45d13f68c5ae
[17:20:02][it:test] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[17:20:02][it:test] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
[17:20:02][it:test] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
[17:20:02][it:test] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
[17:20:02][it:test] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
[17:20:02][it:test] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createUnhandledAlertException(ErrorHandler.java:169)
[17:20:02][it:test] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:141)
[17:20:02][it:test] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:458)
[17:20:02][it:test] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:462)
[17:20:02][it:test] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getTitle(RemoteWebDriver.java:204)
[17:20:02][it:test] at Browser_Steps.I_should_see_that_the_browser_was_launched(Browser_Steps.java:102)
[17:20:02][it:test] at ?.Then I should see that the browser was launched(Browsers.feature:7)
```

**Chrome Driver Error**

```
[17:20:19][it:test] Started ChromeDriver
[17:20:19][it:test] port=1099
[17:20:19][it:test] version=23.0.1240.0
[17:20:19][it:test] log=C:\BuildAgent1\work\6df7fefd08b17c16\chromedriver.log
[17:29:26][it:test] The build myDB::selenium_ci #23 {builId=34261} has been running for more than 10 minutes. Terminating...
[17:29:26][it:test] [Execution timeout] {build.status.text}
[17:29:29][it:test] Dumping threads before termination:
[17:29:29][it:test] PID: 7088, PPID: 6128, Command line: \\usrduws708221\SHARED_TOOLS\java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe -Dagent.home.dir=C:\BuildAgent1 -Dagent.name=USRDUWS345623-MyDB1 -Dagent.ownPort=9091 -Dagent.work.dir=C:\BuildAgent1\work -Dbuild.number=23 -Dbuild.vcs.number=76 -Dbuild.vcs.number.1=76 -Dbuild.vcs.number.selenium_ci=76 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.m2.conf -Dcom.jetbrains.maven.watcher.report.file=C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp\maven-build-info.xml -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Dfile.separator=\ -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp -Dmaven.home=\\usrduws708221\SHARED_TOOLS\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4 -Dos.arch=x86 "-Dos.name=Windows 7" -Dos.version=6.1 -Dpath.separator=; -Dteamcity.agent.cpuBenchmark=325 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.agent_url=http://localhost:9091/RPC2 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.build_id=34261 -Dteamcity.auth.password=sYOEwtcTr6zExWPuECfytw8Nbfb4c1cd -Dteamcity.auth.userId=TeamCityBuildId=34261 -Dteamcity.build.changedFiles.file=C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp\changedFiles7023604667624871531.txt -Dteamcity.build.checkoutDir=C:\BuildAgent1\work\6df7fefd08b17c16 -Dteamcity.build.id=34261 -Dteamcity.build.properties.file=C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.build686343423326544568.properties -Dteamcity.build.tempDir=C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp -Dteamcity.build.workingDir=C:\BuildAgent1\work\6df7fefd08b17c16 -Dteamcity.buildConfName=selenium_ci -Dteamcity.buildType.id=bt300 -Dteamcity.configuration.properties.file=C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.config4225430352183826801.properties -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitaddin=C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitAddin-NUnit -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher=C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher.msbuild.task=C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.dll -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher1.1=C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher1.1.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0=C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0.vsts=C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.VSTS.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.platform=C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.PlatformProcessRunner.1.1.exe -Dteamcity.maven.watcher.home=C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\mavenPlugin\maven-watcher -Dteamcity.projectName=myDB -Dteamcity.runner.properties.file=C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.runner1044140889240461617.properties -Dteamcity.tests.recentlyFailedTests.file=C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp\testsToRunFirst8927992996360649639.txt "-Dteamcity.version=7.0.1 (build 21326)" -Duser.country=US -Duser.home=C:\ -Duser.language=en -Duser.name=SYSTEM -Duser.timezone=America/New_York -Duser.variant= -classpath \\usrduws708221\SHARED_TOOLS\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar; org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f C:\BuildAgent1\work\6df7fefd08b17c16\pom.xml -B -Dmaven.repo.local=//Usrduws708221/shared_tools/maven/repository test -s C:\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp\maven_settings_1267417561803171768.xml
[17:29:29][it:test] 2012-10-23 17:29:29 Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.8-b03 mixed mode): "Thread-2" prio=6 tid=0x0000000006fc4800 nid=0x18ac runnable [0x000000000b7af000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158) - locked <0x00000007aba50a78> (a java.io.InputStreamReader) at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167) at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136) at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299) - locked <0x00000007aba50a78> (a java.io.InputStreamReader) at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362) at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:129) "Thread-1" prio=6 tid=0x0000000006fc4000 nid=0x3f0 runnable [0x000000000b5df000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220) at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256) at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317) - locked <0x00000007aba44fb0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306) at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158) - locked <0x00000007aba4dd20> (a java.io.InputStreamReader) at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167) at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136) at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299) - locked <0x00000007aba4dd20> (a java.io.InputStreamReader) at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362) at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:129) "ThreadedStreamConsumer" prio=6 tid=0x0000000006fc3000 nid=0x1ecc waiting on condition [0x000000000b47f000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) - parking to wait for <0x00000007aba1cba0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987) at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399) at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.internal.Java15BlockingQueue.take(Java15BlockingQueue.java:40) at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamConsumer$Pumper.run(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:68) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) "resolver-4" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000006fc2800 nid=0x1b68 waiting on condition [0x000000000b27f000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) - parking to wait for <0x00000007af7b9ae8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987) at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) "resolver-3" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000006fc1800 nid=0x1f7c waiting on condition [0x000000000b17f000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) - parking to wait for <0x00000007af7b9ae8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987) at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) "resolver-2" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000009dbf000 nid=0x1cec waiting on condition [0x000000000900f000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) - parking to wait for <0x00000007af7b9ae8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987) at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) "resolver-1" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000a04c800 nid=0x1878 waiting on condition [0x0000000008e7f000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) - parking to wait for <0x00000007af7b9ae8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987) at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) "Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000006eb3800 nid=0x19d4 runnable [0x0000000000000000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000006ea2800 nid=0x1a58 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000006e9b000 nid=0x1e1c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE "Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000006e9a000 nid=0x14ec waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE "Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000006e99800 nid=0x1f74 runnable [0x0000000000000000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE "Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x0000000006e3e000 nid=0x14e4 in Object.wait() [0x0000000007b7f000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor) at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) - waiting on <0x00000007af6a0330> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock) at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118) - locked <0x00000007af6a0330> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock) at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134) at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159) "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000006e3a800 nid=0x1120 in Object.wait() [0x0000000007a7f000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor) at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) - waiting on <0x00000007af6a0568> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock) at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485) at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116) - locked <0x00000007af6a0568> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock) "main" prio=6 tid=0x0000000000498000 nid=0x34c runnable [0x00000000026de000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Native Method) at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:151) at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:88) at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:191) at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:98) at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:200) at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:177) at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:135) at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:98) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352) "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000006e2f000 nid=0x1fe4 runnable "GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000004ac800 nid=0x1b90 runnable "GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000004ae000 nid=0x11cc runnable "GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000004b0000 nid=0x1244 runnable "GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000004b1800 nid=0x17d8 runnable "GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000004b5000 nid=0x1cbc runnable "GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000004b6800 nid=0x1b14 runnable "GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000004b8000 nid=0x1dc4 runnable "GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000004ba000 nid=0x1ef0 runnable "VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000006ecc800 nid=0x184c waiting on condition JNI global references: 1110
```

My tests are setup using Cucumber-JVM and within the step definitions I'm trying to execute the Selenium drivers.  I was sure to follow the setup steps outlined on the selenium site and I am currently at a lost as to why the the project does not execute through TeamCity.

I'd be happy to send my test project if that helps with the troubleshooting. Any fresh insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the path to the IEDriverServer and ChromeDriverServer? We are using IEDriver and ChromeDriver to run the tests using Jenkins. We have set up following properties in the pom file and IEDriverServer and ChromeServer files are placed at the root of the project.

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
  <webdriver.chrome.driver>chromedriver.exe</webdriver.chrome.driver>
  <webdriver.ie.driver>IEDriverServer.exe</webdriver.ie.driver>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

You can see the these are exe files, because we are using windows slave machine to run the tests, if you are using the linux machines as your test runner machine then you can change it.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. I will try that and see that works.  My issue is that it looks like the webdrivers are hanging when they try to execute through the build-agent.  I am successfully able to run the webdrivers locally on my machine and on the machine where our build agent lives.  However, when I try to run it through the TeamCity application or through IntelliJ(Remote run) the drivers hang.  I will give this a try and see if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately the drivers are still hanging :( even with these settings